# Spiral or Spin at a set angle? "Golden angle"

Tags: modeling

Is there an easier way to spin an object at a set angle?

The picture below was done manually by duplicating and rotating each object 137.5 degrees (Fibonacci's Golden Angle) each time, but im wondering if there is an easier way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the *Array* modifier:

Create your petal, move it a bit away from its origin in *Edit* mode, create an empty at the same position as this origin, give your petal an *Array* modifier with the empty as *Object Offset*:

[image]

Now rotate the empty on Z:

[image]

You can precisely set its angle in the *N* panel:

[image]

Note that if you move or scale your empty it will also affect the location and scale of the instances.

Answer (score 5):

If you have an object like this and your pivot point is in the center like here:

[image]

you can press:

SHIFT-D -> R -> (angle you want) -> [Return]

Then just hit SHIFT-R as long as you want.

result:

[image]